# How to create the dynamodb table using serverless.yml and delete the items of it using python boto3?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, serverless

I've created the dynamodb table using serverless.yml as below:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    myTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        TableName: myTable
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: firstname
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: lastname
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: firstname
            KeyType: RANGE
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        SSESpecification:
          SSEEnabled: true
```

But I've got this issue:

> An error occurred: myTable - One or more parameter values were
> invalid: Number of attributes in KeySchema does not exactly match
> number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions (Service:
> AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
> Request ID: PEI9OT7E72HQN4N5MQUOIUQ18JVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG;
> Proxy: null).

Could you help me creating the dynamodb table using serverless.yml?
And how can I delete the items that first name is "First" in this table using python boto3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep your `KeySchema` you have to **drop** `lastname` from `AttributeDefinitions`:

```
Resources:
  myTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      TableName: myTable
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: firstname
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: firstname
          KeyType: RANGE
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: true
```

But if you want to keep `lastname`, you could **define** [local secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) for your table:

```
Resources:
  myTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      TableName: myTable
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: firstname
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: lastname
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: firstname
          KeyType: RANGE
      LocalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: by-lastname
          KeySchema: 
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: lastname
            KeyType: RANGE
          Projection: 
            ProjectionType: ALL
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: true
```

With the above, you can sort for `lastname` using the LSI, while `firstname` would be used in the primary table.

> how can I delete the items that first name is "First" in this table using python boto3?

You **can't do it directly** with or without boto3, unless you want to perform [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html), which should be avoided as it can be expensive and is not efficient. To general solution is to define a [Global Secondary Indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) where the `firstname` would be the new primary key. Then you would query the GSI for the `firstname` of interest to obtain the `id` of the record you want to delete. If you have several records with same `firstname`, which probably will be the case, you get a number of records back (GSI primary keys **don't need to be unique**, unlike for the primary table).

Example table with LSI and GSI:

```
Resources:
  myTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      TableName: myTable
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: firstname
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: lastname
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: firstname
          KeyType: RANGE
      LocalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: by-lastname
          KeySchema: 
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: lastname
            KeyType: RANGE
          Projection: 
            ProjectionType: ALL
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: firstname-gsi
          KeySchema: 
            - AttributeName: firstname
              KeyType: HASH
          Projection: 
            ProjectionType: ALL
          #ProvisionedThroughput: 
          #  ProvisionedThroughput        
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason is that all of your AttributeNames in `AttributeDefinitions` must be included in the `KeySchema` as well. I can see the `lastname` attribute is missing in there.

Comment: Can you please attach the sample?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the 'lastname' attribute from the AttributeDefinitions. Anything defined as an AttributeDefinitions must be used in the KeySchema section. Don't forget to export your TableName, Arn, and StreamArn so that you can reference them in other services and IAM policies.

https://carova.io/snippets/serverless-aws-cloudformation-output-stack-variables

Another bonus for exporting variables like the TableName or StreamArn in your CloudFormation Stack is you can reference them across different CloudFormation Stacks.

https://carova.io/snippets/serverless-aws-reference-other-cloudformation-stack-variables