# Serverless.yml DynamoDB Error ValidationException: Provided list of item keys contains duplicates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless, dynamodb-queries

I Keep getting the following error on my serverless.yml configurations file.
"Serverless: DynamoDB - created table transactions

Validation Exception ------------------------------------

ValidationException: Provided list of item keys contains duplicates
"
What could be the problem?
Here’s the entire .yml file.
Thanks…!

```yaml
service: dynamo
useDotenv: true
configValidationMode: error
frameworkVersion: ^2.52.0

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

custom:
  dynamodb:
    stages:
      - dev
    start:
      port: 8000
      inMemory: true
      heapInitial: 200m
      heapMax: 1g
      migrate: true
      seed: true
      convertEmptyValues: true
    seed:
      dev:
        sources:
          - table: transactions
            sources: [./txs.json]
  
functions:
  app:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: transactions
          method: get
  UI:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: 
          path: UI
          method: get

resources:
  Resources:
    transactionsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: transactions
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: country
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: createdAt
            AttributeType: N
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: country
            KeyType: HASH  
          - AttributeName: createdAt
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: country_created_at_index
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: country
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: createdAt
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1

plugins:
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-bundle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GlobalSecondaryIndexes` has **exactly same keys** are your main table. You need different key pairs. Otherwise there is no point for `GlobalSecondaryIndexes`.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, could you please elaborate.
I need to seed the created table, then query sort its items by GSIs 'country' and 'createdAt'.
A single transaction looks like:
{
    "id":"0",
    "amount":793.93,
    "country":"BW",
    "createdAt":1606186591726,
    "updatedAt":1606186591726,
    "currency":"USDT",
    "bitcoinAddress":"19xiZnXJexGgC6R1Tp9M8L7P8MsRhCE5",
    "customerName":"Jenny Kunze",
    "customerEmail":"Lavonne.Oberbrunner@yahoo.com",
    "customerId":"Kayla_Hilll"
}
How do i fix serverles.yml to stop the duplicate keys issue?

Comment: @Vakindu Just remove your `GlobalSecondaryIndexes`. Its not needed.

Comment: Hey thanks, I found the solution in a contribution you made last year.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64063665/3639372

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:
Played around with LocalSecondaryIndexes, till I did this.

```
service: dynamo
useDotenv: true
configValidationMode: error
frameworkVersion: ^2.52.0

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

custom:
  dynamodb:
    stages:
      - dev
    start:
      port: 8000
      inMemory: true
      heapInitial: 200m
      heapMax: 1g
      migrate: true
      seed: true
      convertEmptyValues: true
    seed:
      dev:
        sources:
          - table: transactions
            sources: [./txs.json]
  
functions:
  app:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: transactions/
          method: get
  ui:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: 
          path: ui/
          method: get

resources:
  Resources:
    transactionsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: transactions
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: country
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: createdAt
            AttributeType: N
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH  
          - AttributeName: createdAt
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        LocalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: id_index
          KeySchema: 
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: country
            KeyType: RANGE
          Projection: 
            ProjectionType: ALL
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: country_created_at_index
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: country
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: createdAt
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1

plugins:
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-bundle
```